# How can I process Bitcoin transactions in my store?

Tags: websites, merchants

What merchant solutions are available to integrate Bitcoin in an online store? Is there a wiki page that describes the different merchant solutions?

Note - This question was originally asked specifically for a PHP store, but since most solutions are platform-agnostic this part was edited away.

Comment: https://github.com/neofutur/bitcoin_simple_php_tools is a work in progress but may be worth watching.

Comment: I edited away the PHP part of this question - most solutions are general purpose anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StrongCoin has developed a PHP script for fast handling of micro transactions. You can read more on it here:

- https://strongcoin.com/blog/bitcoin_micropayments_with_strongcoin
- http://www.thebitcointrader.com/2011/12/monetizing-blog-with-bitcoin.html?m=1

Comment: _EDIT - This demo is now defunct but I've left the article here for reference._

Answer (score 2):

You can use the osCommerce shopping cart and there is a payment module here ( https://github.com/weex/oscommerce-bitcoin ) that works but could use some testing. There is also a bounty of 4.75 BTC if you do in-fact create the first public store using it.

Interacting via php natively is not very easy but typically what's done is to use jsonrpc to talk to a locally running bitcoind (Bitcoin daemon). The module mentioned above provides an example of jsonrpc usage.

Answer (score 1):

PHP developer intro
 - http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/PHP_developer_intro

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Strongcoin, there is also [Bitpay](https://bitpay.com/), which offers more manageable / flexible merchant solutions to developers for a small fee. This only covers your users who want to buy with Bitcoin, however.

Answer (score 0):

An up to date light-weight library is being developed that interfaces with the bitcoin network, includes great extras for example: *generating receipts* that saves total cost as well as the list of product ids(and verifyable checksums for data integrity), *no database integration required*.  There is also the bitcoin *address ownership verification* function as well.

Its called **Bitcoin Development Kit** the link to the source code is here: https://github.com/Xenland/Bitcoin-Development-Kit

The website is http://BitcoinDevKit.com